# Cannot iterate over a String HashSet using foreach in Powershell when populating data using Add() method

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, output, hashset

Here my HashSet is generated as well as populated correctly which is evident by the **$hashSet.Contains("hi")** line. Only problem is that I am not able to iterate over this string HashSet and output the unique string items just because I am using the Add() method to fill in the string items.

I tried both ways using **GetEnumerator()** and **Keys**.

```
$hashSet = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]';


$hashSet.Add("hi");
$hashSet.Add("hello");
$hashSet.Add("hi");


foreach ($h in $hashSet.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "$($h.Name): $($h.Value)"
}

foreach ($h in $hashSet.Keys) {
    Write-Host "${h}: $($hashSet.Item($h))"
}

$hashSet.Contains("hi")
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
PS C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> C:\Users\SomeUser\powershell\HashsetInPowershell.ps1
True
True
False
: 
: 
True
```

Comment: There is no `Keys` property on `HashSet`. Use `Set-StrictMode` while testing to catch such problems. `HashSet` is not a dictionary and doesn't contain values, so enumerating in the way you do isn't meaningful. `foreach ($h in $hashSet) { $h }` will output the values (and of course so will just `$hashSet`, due to PowerShell's automatic unrolling behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was treating a HashSet like a Dictionary. [Set-StrictMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-7#:~:text=Description,basic%20best%2Dpractice%20coding%20rules.) will be handy tool to identify errors like this.

Sharing the correct script below.

```
$hashSet = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]';


[void] $hashSet.Add("hi");
[void] $hashSet.Add("hello");
[void] $hashSet.Add("hi");


foreach ($h in $hashSet) {
    Write-Host "${h}"
}

$hashSet.Contains("hi")
```

Output

```
PS C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> C:\Users\SomeUser\powershell\HashsetInPowershell.ps1
hi
hello
True
```